# Is there anyway to play Runescape in the Tor Browser?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, java, help

I was just wandering, because I have searched for a while now and haven't had any luck yet. Runescape uses Java and when I go to the site to play the game, it says I must download Java. I already have Java, so if anyone has any information it is much appreciated!

Comment: Which Operating System are you using?

Answer (score 1):

As you notice the issue is that Java is running the game, and therefor Java is opening the ports. At this point it's now more of a challenge of getting Java to run over Tor. Usually I would make something like this to replace the default java binary:

```
torify java.exe $0
```

Which would then run Java over Tor in replacement of the default Java. However, this runs as an Applet/JNI (browser plugin) and is therefor probably linking directly to a shared library, which makes it more complicated to hook into.

If you can get Runescape as a standalone EXE or Jar, you can do the `torify` trick I showed earlier. The `$0` won't work on Windows though so you can probably just remove that (adds all arguments)